# Printing barcode is not working in odoo receipt? code 39 format is not working?

Tags: odoo, barcode, odoo-9, point-of-sale, receipt

I am tried all these codes. But it's not working? Actually I am adding '*' with barcode, but it does not work. Do I need to configure or do any changes on barcode nomenclature?

```
<img t-att-src="'/report/barcode/?type=%s&amp;value=%s&amp;width=%s&amp;height=%s' % ('EAN13', '2210000000001', 600, 100)" style="width:300px;height:50px;"/>
<barcode encoding="code128">
<t t-esc='receipt.orderbarcode' />
</barcode>


<barcode encoding="CODE39">
<t t-esc='receipt.orderbarcode' />
</barcode>
```

Any advice?

Answer (score 1):

According to the [report module of Odoo](https://github.com/odoo/odoo/blob/9.0/addons/report/controllers/main.py#L62) you should try out `Standard39` or `Extended39` as encoding.